# Confluent Kafka Connect on Kubernetes - cannot override config properties

Tags: kubernetes, confluent-platform

I run Confluent Kafka on Kubernetes and I am unable to override the Kafka Connect connectors properties.

I have added the following to the Kafka Connect CR, but to no avail:

```
apiVersion: platform.confluent.io/v1beta1
kind: Connect
metadata:
  name: connect
  namespace: confluent
spec:
  replicas: 3
  image:
    application: confluentinc/cp-server-connect:7.0.0
    init: confluentinc/confluent-init-container:2.2.0
  configOverrides:
    server:
      - connector.client.config.override.policy=All
```

What is required to set this property in the context of a Kubernetes deployment ?

Thanks

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I am facing similar issue